# ¿Cómo encontrar el artículo gramatical cuando usamos palabras del inglés en nuestras frases?

Tags: gramática, género, artículos, inglés

A modo de ejemplo, en programación podemos hablar de "*la request* de un usuario" como también "*el request* de un usuario" (solicitud de información a través del navegador).

Si bien se da lugar a la ambigüedad (ya que "request" no tiene género), me pregunto si existe un criterio o regla gramatical que permita definir el uso correcto del artículo para estos casos.

En mi cabeza no funciona decir "el request", ya que si estoy hablando en español, naturalmente uso el artículo del significado de la traducción al español, en este caso sería "la solicitud" o "la petición". Si digo "el request", estaría hablando de "el solicitud". ¿Es correcto pensarlo de esa manera?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

En realidad, no puede existir una regla gramatical que rija la combinación de palabras en distintos idiomas (artículo en español, sustantivo en inglés), puesto que se trata de sistemas diferentes, cada uno con sus propias normas.

Lo que existe en la práctica son usos de los hablantes que se relacionan con el género gramatical que se atribuye a la traducción de la palabra en inglés.

Cuando dices "el *request*", seguramente estás pensando en "el pedido". Cuando dices "la *request*", seguramente estás pensando en "la solicitud".

Cuando el sustantivo en inglés tiene como traducción un sustantivo de un solo género, entonces se usará el artículo correspondiente. Por ejemplo, decimos "el *mouse*" (el ratón) y "la *playstation*" (la consola de juego).